# How to edit file on remote machine with text editor?

Tags: ssh, editors

I am on a Windows machine, and I am using NoMachine to connect to a development box. Unfortunately, the box runs on RHEL5, so lots of software is not supported. I want to use Sublime Text. Is there a way for me to edit files on my development box from Windows after connecting to the box through NoMachine?

Comment: "Unfortunately, the box runs on RHEL5", sorry but there is nothing unfortunate about that ;)

Answer (score 10):

You may also use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) (using ssh) to navigate remotely (similar to windows explorer).
When you edit file via WinSCP, it will download it locally and start your preferred editor (check in the options).
Once you save the local file, WinSCP will automatically upload it to it's remote location.
This gives the ability to edit remote files with the feeling of local file editing.

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to ssh into the box, why not give [the SFTP plugin for Sublime Text 2](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) a try?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have ssh access to the machine, you might want to try something like [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/download/) with Dokan SSHFS. From its web page:

> Dokan SSHFS is a program that mounts remote file systems using SSH.

There's a more in-depth tutorial on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1027820).

Comment: I do not always get the most up to date files. When I create a new file in my dev box, it doesn't show up on my Windows machine.

Comment: @egidra this is odd... maybe a bug in Dokan? (I never used it, was the first result for googling "sshfs for Windows").